# Template class copy construcor from different type: should it follow the Rule of Five?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, copy-constructor

I have the following class:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
  A(const T& value): m_value(value)
  {
  }

  template <typename M>
  A(const A<M>& other): A(T(other.m_value))
  {
  }

private:
  T m_value;
};
```

Should this class follow the [Rule of Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)#Rule_of_Five)? Or `template <typename T>template <typename M>
  A<T>::A(const A<M>& other)` is not considered a copy constructor?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167201/copy-constructor-of-template-class

Comment: FWIW, try and shoot for the [Rule of Zero](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-constructors-assignments-and-desctructors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule of five exists because *if* you have a copy constructor then that's probably because you can't use the automatically-generated one, which in turn is probably because you have some indirection that needs to be taken care of. When that's so, you usually also need to take care of it during assignment and destruction.

What you have is not a copy constructor. It converts from another type. There is no indication in your code that the member `m_value` needs special handling during assignment or destruction. Furthermore, the copy-constructor that you *do* have performs no special operations.

If you can think of some code that you need to put in said special member functions, then go ahead and do it. Otherwise, you don't need them.

General rules can be useful but you do ultimately still need to make design decisions based on thinking! You don't implement functions just because a rule of thumb said that you may need to.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard (15.8.1 Copy/move constructors)

> 1 A **non-template constructor** for class X is a copy constructor if
>   its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const
>   volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all
>   other parameters have default arguments

So this

```
  template <typename M>
  A(const A<M>& other): A(T(other.m_value))
  {
  }
```

is not a copy constructor. It is a conversion constructor.

I do not see here the relation with the Rule of Five.

Comment: Thanks! Then, I guess I do not need to follow the Rule of Five, am I right?

Comment: @apalomer It depends on design decision: how the class will be used and with which data types. In any case you can explicitly specialize the class.

Comment: I asked about the rule of five because it sais that if the copy constructor is implemented the rest should be implemented as well. So if that was a copy constructor I should implement the rest.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @apalomer It said "should _probably_ be implemented as well". It's a rule of thumb, not a law!